# Installing NextCloud on Windows (IIS/PHP/MariaDB)

Tags: php, iis, mariadb, nextcloud

I'm having some problems installing NextCloud on Windows 10/2016...

I'd tried also installing under XAMPP
 
but NextCloud keeps failing to start...

Anybody has some info/tutorials
or know where to go to get info
about installing NextCloud on Windows...

Preferably with IIS...
but can also be with Apache or Nginx...

or under XAMPP or WAMP...

Thanks